# String is not showing up in JFrame

Tags: java, string, user-interface

I'm programming a little game where i want to show up a StartScreen and after clicking on it the game will start. But the String's don't show up.

The code is:

```
int nRows = 115;
int nCols = 42;
int[][] grid;
Font smallFont;


public hitit() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1150,420));
    setBackground(Color.orange);
    setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 48));
    smallFont = getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD,18);
    setFocusable(true);


}

void drawStartScreen(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.setFont(smallFont);
    g.drawString("hit it",600,100);
    g.drawString("(click to start)", 250, 240);     
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics2D gg) {
    super.paintComponent(gg);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gg;
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);


    drawStartScreen(g); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("hit it");
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.add(new hitit(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I tried to implement a run-method but that didn't changed the problem

Comment: Show your whole code.

Comment: You posted the code for a class named `hitit`, correct?

Comment: @Abra Correct. Accidentally deleted the class name and also forgot to write the imports, but that isn't the problem because i do Auto Import.

Answer (score 0):

So I copy-pasted the code into a new file and now it's actually working
I don't know why, but the position for the two strings was not problem.

```
package testetetetet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class hitit extends JPanel {


int nRows = 115;
int nCols = 42;
Font smallFont;

public hitit() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1150, 420));
    setBackground(Color.orange);
    setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 48));
    setFocusable(true);

    smallFont = getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 18);
}

void drawStartScreen(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.setFont(smallFont);
    g.drawString("hit it", 1150/2, 190);

    g.drawString("(click to start)", 1150/2, 240);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics gg) {
    super.paintComponent(gg);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gg;
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    drawStartScreen(g);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setTitle("hit it");
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.add(new hitit(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);


}

}
```

Comment: _now it's actually working I don't know why_ Well, you changed the class of the parameter for method `paintComponent()` from `Graphics2D` to `Graphics`.

Answer (score -1):

There's so much wrong with this code I don't even know where to begin.

I guess for a start this mess won't compile. `public hitit()` is clearly missing a return type, and it's impossible to say what component are you using there and where does `public void paintComponent(Graphics2D gg)` method belong.

In general though the whole approach seems to be wrong - why do you want to draw text manually instead of using an available component like [javax.swing.JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)?

Comment: The default layout manager for the content pane of a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, hence no need to explicitly set it.

Comment: It appears that `hitit` is the name of the class, hence `public hitit()` would be the constructor, in which case it won't have a return type.

Comment: Then it should be capitalized as Hitit according to Java code conventions.

Comment: Whatever, even HiTit - as long as it starts with a capital letter.

Comment: Obviously. It's not for the compiler - it's for the reader who tries to understand the code. Following convention in this case would have removed confusion regarding hitit() being method or a constructor.

Comment: Every code convention is not for the compiler. Compilers don't care.